# PHP Class for logins

Tags: php, authentication

I am looking for a good class for logins.  I don't need a login or registration form.  Just the behind the scenes stuff mostly.  Looking for recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP Login System w/ Admin Feature](http://www.evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features) is always a good example

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you looking for? User verification, complete form handling, etc...

Comment: Don't ask questions in answer-format. If you have questions, post them as comments.

Comment: I am looking for something that verifies and redirects.  I have the forms completely built out including creation of an account and login.